# Obtaining user's contact list profile photos using live sdk

Tags: c#-4.0, outlook, windows-store-apps, windows-8.1, live-sdk

I want to get a profile picture for an user's contacts. I'm using live sdk with the scope "wl.basic" but I only get the following,

```
{"id":"contact.6c9151b7000000000000000000000000", "first_name":"Jaiganesh alc", "last_name":null, "name":"Jaiganesh alc", "is_friend":false, "is_favorite":true, "user_id":null, "email_hashes":[], "updated_time":"2013-11-18T12:37:22+0000", "emails":{"preferred":null, "account":null, "personal":null, "business":null, "other":null}}
{"id":"contact.48a6e7c1000000000000000000000000", "first_name":"John", "last_name":"Smith", "name":"John Smith", "is_friend":false, "is_favorite":false, "user_id":null, "email_hashes":["97c370d92fa77d98e7b20014a2ad3d1a67aef140ae0f885b51f951f59dd9f6f5"], "updated_time":"2014-02-25T10:39:12+0000", "emails":{"preferred":"sdj@hjgsf.com", "account":null, "personal":"sdj@hjgsf.com", "business":null, "other":null}}
```

How do a profile picture for the contacts?

Answer (score 0):

As I see you get data as Json format. If you can paste it in that [site](http://jsoneditoronline.org/), you can see the related format.

You can get data by using [json parse methods.](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseJSON/)

Comment: Thankyou, but, my question is to get attribute 'picture 'in that Json!